# Get all children of a parent - hierarchical data using SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, hierarchy, hierarchical-data

I'm trying to learn how to query hierarchical data to return all children of a parent (parent email is given). Here is my query:

```
WITH emp AS (
  SELECT
    PersonnelNumber,
    Email,
    ReportsToPersonnelNbr,
    1 AS level
  FROM tbl
  WHERE Email = 'XYZ'
 
  UNION ALL
   
  SELECT
    e.PersonnelNumber,
    e.Email,
    e.ReportsToPersonnelNbr,
    emp.level + 1
  FROM tbl e INNER JOIN emp
  ON e.ReportsToPersonnelNbr = emp.PersonnelNumber
)
SELECT e.PersonnelNumber, e.Email, e.ReportsToPersonnelNbr, e.level
FROM emp e
ORDER BY e.level;
```

I'm getting the results as expected however it is taking a longer time to return the results. For example, 2 minutes to return ~300 rows. How do I fix that?

UPDATE: I ran the following sql query:

```
CREATE INDEX [IDX_ReportsToPersonnelNbr] ON tbl(ReportsToPersonnelNbr)
```

however I still see it is taking a longer time to return the results.

Comment: A `WHERE` clause I'd imagine.  `WHERE sup.PersonnelNumber < 400`

Comment: The recursion looks for the ReportsToPersonnelNbr of the table. So f.e. a non-unique index on that field would propable speed it up. Btw, [stop using the outdated comma join syntax](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins). It was already outdated in the previous century.

Comment: Could you please clarify what do you mean by "a non-unique index on that field"?

Comment: Thanks! Updated the query to use Inner Join.

Comment: Index creation syntax [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql). The default is non-unique. To understand why a index helps, ponder which is faster to find something in a book, going through all pages, or look for the page in the index.

Comment: @LukStorms please see the updated question. thx!

Comment: Not sure. 300 doesn't seem like much. Could run an [explain plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/display-an-actual-execution-plan) to see what happening, but a beginner won't understand much from it. And doesn't seem to be some circular loop. F. e. `A -> B -> C -> A ->...  ` or it would have hit the default [MAXRECURSION](https://sqlhints.com/tag/maxrecursion-sql-server/) limit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to index your table better. Think about how the server is going to find the rows that you want, and bear in mind that your indexes need to cover all necessary columns.

For your query to perform well, you are going to want the following two indexes

```sql
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_ReportsToPersonnelNbr] ON tbl
  (Email) INCLUDE (PersonnelNumber, ReportsToPersonnelNbr)
  WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON);

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX2_ReportsToPersonnelNbr] ON tbl
  (ReportsToPersonnelNbr) INCLUDE (PersonnelNumber, Email)
  WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON);
```