# SQL query - optional WHERE clause

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL query:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@$"
    WITH emp AS (
        SELECT *, 1 AS Level
        FROM {tableName}
        WHERE PersonnelNumber = {personnelNumber}
 
        UNION ALL
   
        SELECT e.*, emp.Level + 1
        FROM {tableName} e INNER JOIN emp
        ON e.ReportsToPersonnelNbr = emp.PersonnelNumber
    )
    SELECT e.*
    FROM emp e
    WHERE e.Level <= {level}; -----------------------> OPTIONAL LINE
", conn);
```

The WHERE condition is required if level >= 1. Otherwise, the WHERE clause is not required.

Meaning,

if level >= 1, use this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@$"
    WITH emp AS (
        SELECT *, 1 AS Level
        FROM {tableName}
        WHERE PersonnelNumber = {personnelNumber}

        UNION ALL

        SELECT e.*, emp.Level + 1
        FROM {tableName} e INNER JOIN emp
        ON e.ReportsToPersonnelNbr = emp.PersonnelNumber
    )
    SELECT e.*
    FROM emp e
    WHERE e.Level <= {level}
", conn);
```

If level < 1, use this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@$"
    WITH emp AS (
        SELECT *, 1 AS Level
        FROM {tableName}
        WHERE PersonnelNumber = {personnelNumber}

        UNION ALL

        SELECT e.*, emp.Level + 1
        FROM {tableName} e INNER JOIN emp
        ON e.ReportsToPersonnelNbr = emp.PersonnelNumber
    )
    SELECT e.*
    FROM emp e;                    
", conn);
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Are you unsure how to build strings conditionally in C#? (Seems like C# already knows what {level} is, so why not just only add the where clause to the string if it's >= 1?)

Comment: Although here level is a number and safe from injection attack, you shouldn't write your SQL command like this way but use parameters. You could either simply create your SQL string conditionally or simply set level to int.MaxValue when it is < 1.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest would be

```
WHERE (e.Level <= {level}) OR ({level} < 1)
```

But depending on indexing, performance may not be optimal. The next alternative would be to inject either the `WHERE` clause or an empty string into the SQL statement.

Comment: Could you please answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71443210/get-all-children-of-a-parent-hierarchical-data-using-sql-query?noredirect=1#comment126481924_71443210

Comment: Setting level to int.MaxValue or create the query string conditionally are simpler IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solutions would be either creating the SQL string conditionally or setting the level to MaxValue.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"
    WITH emp AS (
        SELECT *, 1 AS Level
        FROM {tableName}
        WHERE PersonnelNumber = {personnelNumber}

        UNION ALL

        SELECT e.*, emp.Level + 1
        FROM {tableName} e INNER JOIN emp
        ON e.ReportsToPersonnelNbr = emp.PersonnelNumber
    )
    SELECT e.*
    FROM emp e" +
    level < 1 ? "" : $" WHERE e.Level <= {level}"
, conn);
```

Or:

```
level = level < 1 ? int.Maxvalue : level;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Different queries**

I deal with problems of this type on the string level:

```
const string X_QUERY_START = @"
    WITH emp AS (
        ...
    SELECT e.*
    FROM emp e";

const string X_QUERY_END = @";"

...

var queryX = X_QUERY_START
  + level >= 1 ? "WHERE e.Level <= {level}" : null
  + X_QUERY_END;
```

You can make your string building better, but this shows the point

**[Hack] Set level to 666**

If level < 1, keep `WHERE e.Level <= {level}` but make it big; big enough it catches all values.